# batch folder rename on macos / linux

Tags: directory, batch, rename

I have 500+ folders which are named with this pattern:

1. May 2020

The folders contain photos, but for some reason the photos creation date in the meta is wrong, or was overwritten. The correct creation date, is the folder name. So in order to get back some order, I would like to rename the folders with this pattern:

2020-05-01

How could i achieve this with a command line tool on macos / brew (linux)?

Comment: Please decide if you want to do this on macOS or Linux. There are likely to be subtle differences.

Comment: The folders are on macOS machine, with brew installed. So most of the linux tools can be loaded, but native OS is macOS. Thanks for any hint. Cheers